# android set custom font to a paint

Tags: android, fonts, set, paint

I want to draw a text to a paint. How to draw it with a custom font (**ex Helvetica** ) and bold also? I would preffer to use a system font and not create it from assets. Thanks.

Comment: "paint": Do you mean `Canvas`?

Comment: yes, I need the paint to set some styles...

Comment: How to set the font according to locale, for example for english we want to use arial.ttf and for korean i want to use gothic_B.ttf. How it is posible with paint on canvas in android

Comment: @DwivediJi: Have you tried posting that as a StackOverflow question, instead of a comment on somebody else's question?

Answer (score 183, accepted):

If by "custom font" you mean a font that you are supplying as an asset, the following code should work:

```
Typeface plain = Typeface.createFromAsset(assetManager, pathToFont); 
Typeface bold = Typeface.create(plain, Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD)
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setTypeface(bold);
canvas.drawText("Sample text in bold",0,0,paint);
```

Comment: Helvetica is not installed, but I've used some installed fonts to compare. If I'm using a font from assets, do you have any idea how to set bold?

Comment: Try: `Typeface plain = Typeface.createFromAsset(assetManager, pathToFont); Typeface bold = Typeface.create(plain, Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD)`.

Comment: @TonythePony your code not work for me.                                                                            Typeface fontFace=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/comic.TTF");
      Typeface face = Typeface.create(fontFace, Typeface.BOLD);
       Paint paint = new Paint();
      paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
      paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
      paint.setTextSize(10);
       paint.setTypeface(face);
        
      paint.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

Comment: Did you try `getContext().getAssets()` ?

Comment: `Typeface.create(plain, Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);` shows error: cannot resolve method create(android.graphics.TypeFace, android.graphics.TypeFace)

Comment: `Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD` gave me issues as well but changing to `Typeface.BOLD` worked

Comment: That is bacause `Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD` is a family, not style and should be used as first param

Comment: mPaint.setFakeBoldText(true); bold can be done this way as well

Comment: How do I load the fonts using the new support library feature : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/downloadable-fonts.html ?

Answer (score 68):

If you are using Android's new Fonts in XML for your fonts, then to get the typeface used for paint you can use:

```
val customTypeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.myfont)
```

or if your min Android API >= 26

```
val customTypeface = resources.getFont(R.font.myfont)
```

Then to apply it to your paint object:

```
mTextPaint.typeface = customTypeface
```

---

For more info check out https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml#fonts-in-code

Comment: This is currently the best answer, please upvote so that others can see it first.

Answer (score 19):

Use this for paint class:

```
 Paint paint = new Paint();
   paint.setTypeface(Typeface.create("Arial",Typeface.ITALIC));
```

Answer (score 11):

If you already have a font in use and want to use a bold version of that you can do this.

```
currentPainter = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
currentPainter.setColor(Color.WHITE);
currentPainter.setTextSize(Utils.sp2px(getResources(), 14)); // set font size
Typeface currentTypeFace =   currentPainter.getTypeface();
Typeface bold = Typeface.create(currentTypeFace, Typeface.BOLD);
currentPainter.setTypeface(bold);
```

I used the answer above, but this modification was necessary for me - so just thought I'd mention it

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use a font from resources (Kotlin):

```
val textPaint = TextPaint()
textPaint.typeface = resources.getFont(R.font.font_name)
```

This might not be related to the question, but this is what I was looking for - maybe somebody would need it too.

Comment: This is the simplest solution, but it only works with SDK 26+. You can also use `ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.font_name)` when targeting older Android versions.

Answer (score 3):

The custom font must be placed in the assets folder.

Maybe the following code can help you

```
Paint p = new Paint();
//Set font
Typeface plain = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "custom_font.ttf");
p.setTypeface(plain);
```

Answer (score 2):

with FontUtils kotlin object

```
object FontUtils {

    private const val FONT_PATH_LATO_REGULAR = "lato_regular.ttf"

    fun getDefaultTypeface(context: Context): Typeface {
        return Typeface.createFromAsset(context.assets, FONT_PATH_LATO_REGULAR)
    }
}
```

then you can use it as:

```
paint.typeface = FontUtils.getDefaultTypeface(context)
```