# How to create a bitmap like creating .csv file on android

Tags: android, bitmap

We can create an csv file and save it in memory card as given in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11341931/how-to-create-a-csv-on-android)

As same way I want to create Bitmap. So please help me how to create bitmap write some text on it?

Comment: What do you mean by create Bitmap ? Are you trying to do some image processing ? What kind of Bitmap you want to create ?

Comment: I want to create an plain bitmap as same size of screen with white or black background and write some strings 6-9 line like we can create csv file and write some string on it line by line and I want save this bitmap in memory card. But I have no Idea please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `Canvas` and `drawText()`.

```
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
Canvas c = new Canvas(bmp);
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
c.drawText("Hello world!", xPos, yPos, paint);
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, new FileOutputStream(destFilePath);
```

You can also set the font and text-size via the `Paint`-object. See [How to set font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042977/android-set-custom-font-to-a-paint) and [`Paint.setTextSize()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#setTextSize%28float%29).