# Java Canvas - How can I implement my own fonts and draw them to my text

Tags: java, android, canvas, fonts, paint

I am using Canvas and Paint to draw my text. There is no option that I can find to change font type

```
    finalScorePaint.setTextSize(72);
    finalScorePaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    canvas.drawText("Your Score is:", 250, 450, finalScorePaint);
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Set a typeface to the paint.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042977/android-set-custom-font-to-a-paint

Comment: it shows you here http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/2D-Graphics/Drawtextwithcustomfont.htm

Comment: Thanks :) What about custom fonts? Like ones downloaded off the internet?

Comment: Im extending the view class. The getAssets() method doesnt work in the view class only in activity. How can I access it?

Answer (score 0):

Try using Canvas.drawPaint() function.