# Custom Font Android Studio With Draw?

Tags: android, android-canvas, paint, android-fonts

I created an "assets" folder and I created a "fonts" folder inside. The custom font is called "dshift.tff". I have my main screen running in a loop with updates and need to create a display with external font.

```
public void drawText(Canvas canvas) {
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    //Tell me what to do here please
}
```

This method is getting called by

```
public void draw(Canvas canvas)
{
    super.draw(canvas);
    //... rest of my code with no more declarations
}
```

Comment: did you check this question?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042977/android-set-custom-font-to-a-paint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the typeface elsewhere such that it is accessible in your `drawText`, as you do not wish to do this every time during rendering -

```
   Typeface type = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/Kokila.ttf");
```

In your drawText, create a `Paint` object and set its typeface

```
   Paint paint = new Paint();
   paint.setTypeface (type);
```

Then draw text using the paint object.